# How can I chose the correct callback for Notification.requestPermission() function?

Tags: javascript

The Notification.requestPermission() function has changed from a callback to a promise based version. You can see this in the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission).

What is the best practice to chose the correct version for the current browser? I tried something like this:

```
 function callback(value) {
   // Do something
 }

 Notification.requestPermission(callback).then(callback);
```

This works, if a promise is present. Sometimes callback is fired twice. Is there any way to pre check, which is the right version for the callback I need?

Comment: `Notification.requestPermission.length` should do, can you try it?

Comment: Your link goes to the german version of the documentation. Please don't do that.

Comment: Why not stick to the promise version?

Comment: @JanDvorak I've updated the link. Sorry. I want to deal with most browsers. The callback version is used for a long time. So there may be browser out there, that does not support the promise version.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution myself. I don't know, if there is a better approach.

```js
    var promise;
    var calledBack = false;

    if(!Notification || Notification.permission === 'denied')
      alert('Notification had been denied');
    else if(Notification && Notification.permission !== 'granted') {
      function callback(result) {
        if(!calledBack) {
          calledBack = true;

          if(result === 'granted') {
            // Do something
          }
        }
      }

      promise = Notification.requestPermission(callback);

      if(promise && typeof promise.then === 'function')
        promise.then(callback);
    }
```

The callback checks, if it has been called. The promise is used if requestPermission returns a promise with function "then".